# Importance of keyword self?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm going through ZetCode's tutorial on PyQt4 GUI development. He gives the following code for making a toolbar -

```
self.toolBar = self.addToolBar('Exit')`
self.toolBar.addAction(exitAction)
```

and this to add a menuBar -

```
menuBar = self.menuBar()                                            
fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
```

self here is that parent class which is a QtGui.QMainWindow.

I don't understand why he uses self.toolBar in the first example but doesn't use self.menuBar in the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `self` at the starting of the variable name makes it the *member variable* or *instance variable*. When you create instance of mainWindow, menuBar already exists on `QMainWindow`. Thus there is no need to save reference to menuBar in a member variable, because you can retrieve it any time in any part of your code by just calling `self.menuBar()`. On the other hand, toolBar does not exist on mainWindow when you create it, you need to add it by calling `self.addToolBar()` and save the reference to toolBar in a member variable in order to perform operations on toolBar in any part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

In your second case as `menuBar` is a reference to `self.menuBar()`, the following code,

```
menuBar = self.menuBar()                                            
fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
```

simply boils down to

```
fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&File')
fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
```

which is not different from the first piece of code that you have

```
self.toolBar = self.addToolBar('Exit')`
self.toolBar.addAction(exitAction)
```

So, if you ask

> I don't understand why he uses self.toolBar in the first example but
>   doesn't use self.menuBar in the second example.

Its because of programming style and a sense of readability that varies from programmer to programmer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the author does use `self.menuBar()`:

```
menuBar = self.menuBar()
```

The above makes `menuBar` refer to the object returned by `self.menuBar()`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> menuBar = self.menuBar()
> ```

This indicates that `self` already has a sense of its menu bar. This method call probably retrieves a pre-existing object, so as such there's no need to store it on the instance, nor would it necessarily be appropriate to do so (if e.g. it's actually someone else's menu bar and the class is just manipulating it).